# How to upload image to facebook cover photo using ios programming ?

Tags: ios

Here I am using fbGraph library to connect facebook and upload photos. It's successfully done.

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
```

But if I try to upload image to facebook cover it is not uploading at all.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/cover"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
```

so can anybody tell me the solution. or another proper way.

Comment: I also have the same query can anybody please sort out it..